# Single line UILabel hugging not working with autoshrink

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I've a UILabel with the following properties:

- A very big font
- Fixed left margin to superview
- Fixed right margin to superview
- Centered vertically
- `Autoshrinks` to a `minimum font size` to avoid truncating the text as much as possible.
- **Single line**
- Vertical hugging priority set to `Required` (1000)

The problem I'm having is that the label **doesn't vertically hug the text**, as you can see in the image bellow there's a lot of space on top and bellow the text.

I uploaded the sample project [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d2mcv55ng2nuyse/LabelAutoshrinkHuggingIssue.zip?dl=0).

Thanks!

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I think auto shrink keeps the text on the same baseline. Since your desired font is so large, it's allocating space for that size font then shrinking the text to the baseline. I say I think that's what's happening. Try setting your font size smaller to see if that's what's causing it. Not an answer, I realize, but may help to understand why it's behaving this way.

Comment: Yes, that's what causing it Mike, seems like hugging doesn't work well with the autoshrink feature of labels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the desired effect with a workaround. It's not the perfect solution and doesn't work on all cases but it did solve my issue at least.

**SUMMARY**

The workaround works as follows:

1. Find the `actual font` (the font that is being actually used by the label).
2. Calculate the text height with the actual font.
3. Use `UIViews`'s `- (UIEdgeInsets)alignmentRectInsets` ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/alignmentRectInsets)) to modify alignment rect that is used by Autolayout to position views based on the actual text height.

With all this, I was able to go from this:

[image]

to this:

[image]

**PROBLEMS**

- Need to set baseline to center
- Only implemented for exceeding height (doesn't work for right and left margins)
- Only for single line labels

**CODE**

Declared a UILabel subclass as follows

```
@implementation HuggingLabel

- (UIEdgeInsets)alignmentRectInsets
{
    if (self.numberOfLines != 1)
    {
        if ([super respondsToSelector:@selector(alignmentRectInsets)])
            return [super alignmentRectInsets];
        else
            return UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    }

    UIFont *fontThatFitsBounds = [self fontThatFitsBounds];
    CGSize textSize = [self.text sizeWithAttributes:@{
                                                      NSFontAttributeName : fontThatFitsBounds
                                                      }];
    CGSize actualSize = self.bounds.size;

    CGFloat exceedingWidth = actualSize.width = textSize.width;
    CGFloat exceedingHeight = actualSize.height - textSize.height;
    CGFloat exceedingHeightTop = exceedingHeight / 2.0f;
    CGFloat exceedingHeightBottom = MAX(0.0f, exceedingHeight / 2.0f + fontThatFitsBounds.descender);

    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(
                                           exceedingHeightTop,
                                           0.0f,
                                           exceedingHeightBottom,
                                           0.0f
                                           );

    return insets;
}

- (UIFont *)fontThatFitsBounds
{
    CGSize currentSize = CGSizeZero;
    CGFloat fontSizeThatFits = self.font.pointSize + 1.0f;

    do {

        fontSizeThatFits = fontSizeThatFits - 1.0f; //try with one point smaller size

        NSDictionary *attributes = [self stringAttributesWithFontOfSize:fontSizeThatFits];
        currentSize = [self.text sizeWithAttributes:attributes];

    } while (currentSize.width > self.bounds.size.width ||
             currentSize.height > self.bounds.size.height);

    return [self.font fontWithSize:fontSizeThatFits];
}

- (NSDictionary *)stringAttributesWithFontOfSize:(CGFloat)fontSize
{
    NSMutableParagraphStyle * paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
    paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = self.lineBreakMode;
    paragraphStyle.alignment = self.textAlignment;

    NSDictionary *attributes = @{
                                 NSFontAttributeName : [self.font fontWithSize:fontSize],
                                 NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle
                                 };

    return attributes;
}

@end
```

Demo project can be downloaded for [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/55qbihirvheqkyp/LabelAutoshrinkHuggingIssue%20%28solved%29.zip?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code :

```
[self.myLabel setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion Piyush but that didn't work :(